# Call acceptance, decline or no response probability

Tags: probability

[image]

Given that a = 0.7, b = 0.6 and c = 0.48,

(a) Find the probability that a customer, randomly chosen from the N potential customers, declines the offer in the second call, given that the offer was not accepted in the first call.

My Answer:
P(declines in 2nd call / offer not accepted in the first call) = $\frac{0.2\times0.35}{0.2}$ = 0.35

Correct answer is $\frac{7}{15}$

(b)  Two customers are chosen at random from the N potential customers. Find the probability that both of them are telephoned  twice and both make no response to the second call.

My Answer: $[{0.2\times0.6} + {0.7\times0.48}]\times2 = 0.912 $

Correct answer is 0.207936

May I know what is wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If offer is not accepted in the first call, it could either have been declined or there was no response.

If $B$ is the event that the offer is not accepted in the first call, then $P(B) = 1 - 0.1 = 0.9$

If $A$ is the event that the offer is rejected in the second call, $P(A \cap B) = 0.2 \times 0.35 + 0.7 \times 0.5 = 0.42$

$ \displaystyle P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac 7 {15}$

For the second question, considering both customers choose independently, you must apply product rule to find the probability that both of them do not respond to the second call. So the desired probability is,

$[{0.2\times0.6} + {0.7\times0.48}]^2$

Comment: Thank you so much. Got it now.

Comment: you are welcome